# Problema enviar mensaje via PHP Gmail

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

Desde mi local tengo puesto un servicio de *Apache* para hacer las comprobaciones antes de subir los archivos a mi pagina de internet. Tengo un apartado de contactos que con el servicio de *Apache* me va perfectamente, pero cuando subo los archivos PHP y hago la prueva en la pagina web, *no recibo nada*.

**PHP**:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';
require 'OAuth.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = "correo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SetFrom("correo@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Pagina web: " . $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: ". $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$mail->AddAddress("correo@gmail.com");

$mail->Send()
  
?>
```

El password que utilizo es una *Contraseña de aplicación* para que me dejara enviar mensajes desde la web.

**JS**:

```
function sendMailPHP() {
    $(".btn-submit").click(function() {
        $(".btn-general").css("pointer-events", "none");
        $(this).val("ESPERE");
    });
    $('.contact').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/email.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $(".btn-general").removeClass("btn-submit");
                $(".btn-general").addClass("btn-send");
                $(".btn-general").val("ENVIADO!");
            }
        });
    });

}
```

A la hora de darle al *Enviar*, me sale el mensaje *"ENVIADO!"* sin problema, pero sigue sin llegarme el mensaje.

**HTML**:

```
<form class="container contact" name="send_email">
                <div class="contact-inputs title">
                    <h1>Explicanos <span class="change-how">tu proyecto</span></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs name">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" class="form-input input-name">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs email">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email" class="form-input input-email">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs phone">
                    <input type="number" name="phone" id="" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-input input-phone">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs message">
                    <textarea type="radio" name="message" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-input input-message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs submit">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn-general btn-submit disabled-button">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Ves algo en los logs de PHP (en apache)?

Comment: En el cPanel de la web en los Logs me sale lo siguiente: PHP Error: Request security check failed (POST /cpsess0795794159/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php?_task=mail&_action=refresh)

Comment: debes ir a las `opciones` de `gmail` en `seguridad` y darle `permitir la conexion de aplicaciones menos segura` saludos!

Comment: @Bryro Lo hice, incluso genere contraseña para que puediera utilizar el correo de Gmail con PHP